# How to index mixed language contents on Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, search-engine, multiple-languages

How to index mixed language contents in Elasticsearch. Let's say that we have a system where people submit contents from various parts of the world. Countries ranges from US, Canada, Europe, Japan, Korea, India, China, Kenya, Arabs, Russia to all other parts of the world.

Contents can be in any language that we can't know beforehand and can even be in mixed language. We don't want to guess the language of the contents and create multiple language specific indexes for each of the inputted language, we believe this is unmanageable.

We need an easy solution to index those contents efficiently in Elasticsearch with full text search capability as well as fuzzy string searching. Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

What is the target you want to achieve? Do you want to have hits only in the language used at query time? Or would you also accept hits in any other language?

One approach would be to run all of elasticsearch's different language analyzers on the input and store the result in separate fields, for instance suffixed by the language of the current analyzer. 
Then, at query time, you would have to search in **all** of these fields if you have no method to guess the most relevant ones.

However, this is likely to explode since you create a multitude of unused duplicates. This is IMHO also less elegant than having separate indices.

I would strongly recommend to evaluate if you really do not know the number of languages you will see during production. Having a distinct index per language would give you much more control over the input/output and enable you to fine tune your engine to the actual use case.

Alternatively, you may start with a simple whitespace tokenizer and evaluate the quality of the search results (per use case).
You will not have language specific stemming but at least token streams for most languages.

Comment: I want to achieve following: 
I have million of records entered by end users from across the world. They entered in their own language and I can't know what language they used during data input. Consider twitter, users write comments in their own language or even mixed languages.

But I want the Chinese keywords to match the Chinese content among all data or Spanish keywords to match Spanish content among all data.

Since the language can be more than hundreds, its not feasibility to build analyser for each language type. I can sacrifice some accuracy for optimised solution.

Comment: Elasticsearch offers 34 different analyzers. Maybe that would get you started? 
If your goal is to build something like Twitter, you'll need a much more elaborate architecture, IMHO. Twitter partnered with bing for language translation, but support "only" 40 languages. See here for details: https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/translate-tweets

Maybe you should avoid early optimization and check whether the number of items users post in rare languages is really significant.

Comment: My goal is not to translate texts. My goal is to have optimized searching mechanism for user submitted text. I need a full text search engine that works alright for all uni-code supported language. I know there is limitations, but there are some other search engines that support multi-language full text search with little effort. I do appreciate your suggestions, but looking for a concrete way of doing it.